# Кнопка выход

Tags: сессия, php, mysql

Авторизация работает на ура (построено на сессиях), а вот кнопка выход (exit.php) выдает ошибку:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send
> session cookie - headers already sent
> by (output started at
> v:\home\test.ru\www\exit.php:2) in
> v:\home\test.ru\www\exit.php on line 5
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send
> session cache limiter - headers
> already sent (output started at
> v:\home\test.ru\www\exit.php:2) in
> v:\home\test.ru\www\exit.php on line 5

Файл exit.php

```
//Запускаем Сессию
session_start();

//Уничтожаем переменные в сессиях
unset($_SESSION['password']);
unset($_SESSION['login']); 
unset($_SESSION['id']);

//Отправляем пользователя на главную страницу.
exit("<html><head><title>Загрузка..</title><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php'></head></html>");
```

Помогите решить вопрос!

Comment: Попробуйте для начала сохранить файл в UTF without BOM

Comment: exit.php куда-то подключается? Если да, то посмотрите, нет ли в этом файле вывода ДО подключения.

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь, что перед `session_start();` нет никакого вывода : пробелов, переводов строки или чего нибудь подобного.

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте в коде `ob_start();`, а также попробуйте после всех `unset` поставить `session_destroy();`.

Comment: destroy отпадает, ошибок больше!

Answer (score 0):

Самый оптимальный вариант и не нужно мудрить. 
Создай файл exit.php и на него ссылку "выход".

```
<?
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/");
exit;
?>
```